Bottom overflow inside SingleChildScrollView when TextFormFields expand on error
I have a signup page with a bunch of TextFormFields that are inside a SingleChildScrollView so the user can scroll when the keyboard pops up. If I hit the signup button while the entries don't pass validation, the TextFormFields expand in height because the error text pops up underneath and my widgets no longer fit on the screen. I don't want to add resizeToAvoidBottomInset=false to my Scaffold because then the bottom TextFormFields may get hidden under the keyboard. Why doesn't the SingleChildScrollView still work with these expanded widgets?
Some of my code:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: screenHeight - screenHeight * 0.03,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // Back button here
                Spacer(),
                // Whole bunch of TextFormFields here
                SizedBox(height: screenHeight * 0.03),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


i really didn't catch your problem. so you mean your SingleChildScrollView not working causing the overflow error?

@gopelkujo it works in the sense that I can scroll when I click on a textfield and the keyboard pops up. It then automatically scrolls the focused TextFormField up above my keyboard so it's in view. However, if I hit the sign up button and some fields don't pass validation the error text shows up underneath, expanding the height of the TextFormField widgets and causing the bottom overflow, even though I have a SingleChildScrollView

Did you put your textformField inside sizedbox?
